# grub2 searches for non-existent harddisk

Tags: hard-drive, boot, grub

After I installed some updates on my Windows 10 partition the system doesn't boot anymore. There are some errors that vanish very quickly, but from what I can grasp they say that some sectors on hd1 cant't be read.

I end up in this mini console "GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.21"
When I enter 'ls' I get

```
(hd0) (hd0,gpt8) (hd0,gpt7) (hd0,gpt6) (hd0,gpt5) (hd0,gpt4) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) (hd1) error: failure reading sector 0xfc from `hd1´.
error: failure reading sector 0xe0 from `hd1´.
error: failure reading sector 0x0 from `hd1´.
```

Now I recognize hd0 which is my harddisk and which has in fact 8 partitions. That is definitely the only harddisk in the system and there is no other drive connected to the laptop.

Is there any way to tell grub2 not to look for hd1?

Comment: Do you have one of those systems with a tiny SSD to speed Windows boot. They are unformatted and just store the fast start up hibernation file, so grub would not be able to read it. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I uploaded my boot information at http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gqPyJmzvj8/ . I had to switch off 'secure boot' to make Boot-Repair boot from a stick. And there is no tiny SSD to speed up booting.

Comment: Reboot and run Boot-Repair in UEFI mode. It shows more UEFI info like: `sudo efibootmgr -v` Are you booting Ubuntu or Opensuse. You show both folders in sda2. Windows updates often turn fast start up back on. You need to turn that off for grub to see Windows partitions. Have you tried configfile? `configfile (hd0,5)/boot/grub/grub.cfg` from grub> Change hd0,5 to your Linux partition with /boot/grub folder.

Comment: I will try that. I have to find a boot image with boot-repair that is UEFI compatible.

Comment: All Ubuntu ISO are both UEFI or BIOS boot. But some installers may configure flash drive for one or the other. It is more how you boot flash drive from system's UEFI boot menu. You should have two entries. I have UEFI:PMAP & PMAP where PMAP alone is the BIOS boot. Many have name or label of flash drive where mine shows PMAP. Or maybe all the OEM (Microcenter) flash drives are labeled PMAP?

Answer (score 0):

```
configfile(hd0,gpt7)/boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

did the trick. I was able to boot into my openSUSE system and then use the yast2 boot loader editor to restore the configuration. The yast tool gave me an error message about some file system not writable, but it worked anyway. Thank you, oldfred!